# C# gRPC client SslCredentials without root rootCertificates

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, grpc

I have an internal application of clients & servers which uses a self signed certificates for Server SSL (each server has it's own ssl certificate)

Because I'm using self signed certificate I have a custom verification logic.

I was able to implement it using .net standard (Grpc.Net.Client)

however I also have clients using .net framework 4.7.2 and I can't figure out how to accomplish it there.
I saw I can use the gRPC.Core library and create SslCredentials with arguments verifyPeerCallback which I can use to add custom certificate validation.

However I must pass the rootCertificates argument which means every client must have access to the public certificate which is what I want to avoid (for example certificate rotation / multiple server behind a FW)

Comment: The client & server are both gRPC